# Xcode apple developer certificate expiration: (0xE8008018)

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning

Just for the record: I had a stranger response from Xcode when I tried to run my app on my device.

> Please verify that your device's clock is properly set, and that your
>   signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018).

My certificate expires today at midnight AND my several provisioning profiles need a serious cleaning.

What is the administrative process to get it all renewed to get a build AND run working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to :

1. Connect to Apple Developer Member Center
2. Click on 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'
3. iOS Apps must not have an expiration date notification or else
   renew it, and come back here
4. Click on 'Provisioning profiles'
5. If no one has 'active' status, that is the problem
6. Add one for 'iOS App Development'
7. Choose the right 'App ID' : your BundleID, or wildcard
8. The next screen should show you valid certificates. If not, go create one (click on 'Certificates' item on the left menu) and come back here
9. Choose one certificate
10. Then you see all the devices you declared in 'Devices', select those on which you want to run your app
11. Give a profile name and generate it
12. You will download a file named : [profile name].mobileprovision
13. Double-click to install it
14. At this step, my problem was solved. Build and run on my phone is ok.

Comment: Always do a Clean! Was the only thing I didn't do... Sigh.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same exact thing only... all my profiles, certificates and everything were up-to-date in the Dev portal.  What fixed it for me was under the General tab of my app's target, changing the 'Team' dropdown to none... and then back to my company.  Forced Xcode to re-request whatever it thought it needed from the Dev Portal.

Back in business...  :-)

Comment: knew it had to be something like this...my app would build on my iPhone but not my iPad, and this seemed to fix the issue after a couple Xcode restarts and "None" toggling

Comment: I had to do something similar. However, changing from none to my company didn't work. So, instead I clicked "Add an Account" and just logged into my developer account. This caused the certificates to refresh and I'm back in business.

Answer (score 5):

Or go to your Utilities/Keychain and delete all the certs there. Run from Xcode and it will sort it all out for you.

Comment: This worked for me only after I went to the Apple Developer website and agreed to new terms & conditions

Comment: I just had to kill certificates listed as revoked in keychain and voila : your advice worked

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a group and suffer this problem, but your colleagues do not, you may ask somebody to export the developer profile as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html

Then import the .developerprofile file.

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All Just delete the developer certificate and install it again.delete the account fomr xcode preferences and add it again.
Works for me

Answer (score 0):

Restarting XCode made XCode solve the problem for me showing this prompt:

[image]

Just pressed "Fix Issue" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all expired certificates from Keychain rest xcode will handle.