# iOS Developer certificate expiration

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have some account with old certificate for an app that is currently in production. It's not duplicate of this question ([Xcode apple developer certificate expiration: (0xE8008018)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372166/xcode-apple-developer-certificate-expiration-0xe8008018)) because I know exactly what to do, but what harm it can does. Since I **do not have** CSR file that was used to create this certificate and app use a lot of push notifications.

Does revoking certificate will break push notifications?

What's about signing? If I revoke certificate I have to regenerate provisioning profile before pushing to store?

[image]

What will happen when I revoke certificate there?

Comment: It will not effect your existing app. It will function as it is. :)

Comment: In your case, Create a new certificate and replace the old cert on push server with newly generated one. Cheers! All the pushes will continue to deliver to users. But make sure do above thing just after creation of new certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does revoking certificate will break push notifications?

**Yes**, if you revoke the certificate you will no longer receive push notifications to the app.

> What's about signing? If I revoke certificate I have to regenerate provisioning profile before pushing to store?

If you create a new certificate and upload it to the server sending the push notifications you will be able to send push notifications again. This **can** be done without the need to build a new binary for the AppStore.

> what harm it can does. Since I do not have CSR file that was used to create this certificate and app use a lot of push notifications.

Create a new certificate request and upload it to the correct app to create a new certificate in the developer portal. You do not need the original CSR file to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You should review the [Apple Support article on Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/).

> Does revoking certificate will break push notifications?

Yes, "you can no longer send push notifications to your app."  At least not until you regenerate the cert and change your application to use the new one.

Distribution:

> - iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)
>
> If your Apple Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will
> not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new
> apps or updates to the App Store.
>
> - iOS Distribution Certificate (in-house, internal use apps)
>
> Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this
> certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is
> signed with a new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> In your case, Create a new certificate and replace the old cert on
>   push server with newly generated one. Cheers! All the pushes will
>   continue to deliver to users. But make sure do above thing just after
>   creation of new certificate.
>
> Push cert is used for communication between your push server and APNS.
>   APNS allows push payload from the servers having valid certificates.
>   So replace the old cert with new one. I done it in past. No issue
>   faced. Push will be effected for the duration you would take to revoke
>   and update the certificates on push server.